# Use SVG colours on an HTML element?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have been messing around with SVGs to see if I can use them in such a way as an almost parent/controller element that is able to pass down its gradient color values to other HTML tag elements.

Basically, I am wanting to find out is it possible to just put a class of `buy-button_normal` on a button tag that would then directly inherit the gradient using `fill: url(#gradient);`. I know that one could just embed the SVG in the button or use it as a background image. But I am trying to figure out if one is just able to directly inherit a colour/gradient from an SVG with a specific ID.

```css
.buy-button {
  border: none;
  width: 18.38rem;
  height: 2.125rem;
  border-radius: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.2rem;
}

.buy-button_normal {
  fill: url(#gradient);
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient _ngcontent-uwo-30="" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="gradient" x1="147.18" x2="147.18" y1="1.83" y2="34.71">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#e55766"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#be1e66"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg  class="buy-button">
  <rect class="buy-button buy-button_normal" height="34.2" rx="2" ry="2" style="disabled" width="294.37">
  </rect>
</svg>

<button class="buy-button buy-button_normal">
  <span  class="buy-button__normal-text">BUYING</span>
    <div  class="spinner buy-button__spinner">
    </div>
</button>
```

Comment: no, but you could use a css gradient instead,

Comment: @RobertLongson yea generally I would. But what we I am trying to achieve makes use of automation where our design department would just have to export a changed SVG image and it would instantly update across the client.

Comment: and they can't update a changed stylesheet the same way?

Comment: Its not that we cant do it manually. Its just to create a method so its not needed. So instead of a developer or someone having to go and change it manually an art person when they done creating the new element can just export and replace an existing version and it will make use of that.